# fail2ban makes nc fail

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I have a problem with `fail2ban` here. (Configs see below)

Before I had it I used

```
nc -4 -d -n -z -w 1 <SERVER IP> 22
```

from my PC in a script to check if the server is reachable on SSH (should return `1`).

**With fail2ban activated it returns `0` though I can connect by `ssh <USER>@<SERVER IP>` just as expected - I use keypairs for authentication.**

I have an iptables firewall based on [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-basic-firewall-template-with-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04) which looks like this:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N ICMP
-N TCP
-N UDP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ICMP
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
-A ICMP -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 433 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

Having `fail2ban` installed and activated with the config below my iptables look like this

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N ICMP
-N TCP
-N UDP
-N f2b-recidive
-N f2b-sshd
-N f2b-sshd-ddos
-N f2b-webmin-auth
-A INPUT -p tcp -j f2b-recidive
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 10000 -j f2b-webmin-auth
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd-ddos
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ICMP
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
-A ICMP -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 433 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A f2b-recidive -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd-ddos -j RETURN
-A f2b-webmin-auth -j RETURN
```

**What is the problem here?**

My first guess would have been some wrong chainlink in the iptables but since I can connect normal I'm quite helpless here.

---

I installed `fail2ban` by

```
sudo apt install fail2ban
```

and have basically the default setup. Only added those two files:
`/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/defaults.local`

```
[DEFAULT]

ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 <MY PC'S IP>/32
bantime  = 3600
findtime  = 600
maxretry = 3

#
# ACTIONS
#

destemail = <MY MAIL ADDRESS>
sender = <SENDER ADDRESS>
mta = sendmail
action = %(action_mwl)s
```

I already added `MY PC'S IP` here because it got blocked using the `nc` command the first time.

`/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/jail.local`

```
[sshd]
enabled = true

[sshd-ddos]
enabled = true

[webmin-auth]
enabled = true

[recidive]
enabled = true
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
banaction = iptables-allports
bantime  = 604800  ; 1 week
findtime = 86400   ; 1 day
maxretry = 5
```

Comment: what you have in `/var/log/fail2ban.log`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem: I thought wrong / just got confused.

`nc` returns `0` on success not on failure! 
My script works fine now and I found the clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933843/why-0-is-true-but-false-is-1-in-the-shell) => In bash `0` means true and `1` means false.